# ECS Task Denied access to S3 ENV file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, environment-variables, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I found a couple of posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65287721/aws-fargate-task-error-resourceinitializationerror-failed-to-download-env-fil) which I thought would solve my issue for me but I am still getting the *failed to download env file* error.

My workflow:

- ECS Cluster running a FARGATE task definition
- Task definition: network mode *awsvpc* on Linux OS. Has a [role with AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy and this in-line policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Envfile",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/docker-assets/.env"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EnvFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/docker-assets"
        }
    ]
}
```

ECS Task Definition:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::my-account:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": [
        {
          "value": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/docker-assets/.env",
          "type": "s3"
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/My-Task",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "my-account.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-app-v1:v1",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "my-app"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "512",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::my-account:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:my-account:task-definition/My-Task:5",
  "family": "My-Task",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.env-files.s3"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "runtimePlatform": null,
  "cpu": "256",
  "revision": 5,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

- The task definition also lists the s3 ARN of the env file.
- I am running with a default VPC and subnet
- The automatic IP is enabled
- My s3 bucket was created with block all public access

Please let me know if any further information might required to help with the answer. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Stating "ecsTaskExecution role" is a bit confusing, because the ECS task has two IAM role settings: the "Execution Role" and the "Task Role".  Please include the task definition in your question.

Comment: Also, as noted in at the top of the documentation you linked, I **highly** recommend using SSM Parameter Store, or SecretsManager, to store these environment variable values instead of storing them in a file in S3.

Comment: I updated the confusing language you pointed out. The role has AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy and and In-line policy with the above JSON.... Also, I tested access from the role to the s3 bucket and s3 file on the policy simulator which shows they are accessible.

Comment: Without seeing your ECS task definition it's impossible to point out if you have an error in your ECS task definition.

Comment: Updated the post to reflect my ECS task definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated my *ecsTaskExecutionRole*'s in-line policy to cover the bucket (with and without slash) and everything under it. This seemed to work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/docker-assets/.env"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```